# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model' and are all correct

Tags: python

im trying to import a module(model) from my routes.py

```
xx/controller/routes.py

xx/model/User.py
```

im using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../model')
from model import User
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you are getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'`.

**If that is the case, simply replace the line `from model import User` with `import User`.**

Why?

When you add `../model` to the path, you are effectively telling Python that it can import files from the directory `xx/model/`. When you then run `from model import User`, you are telling python to find `model` inside `xx/model/` - but there is no `model` folder or file inside the `xx/model` directory, so Python throws an error. Instead, `import User` will tell Python to import the `User` file from `xx/model/`, which is what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you, is it. i've printed the path which model was referencing and i could solve the problem. thank you bro <3